# Is it possible to have different .DEF files per build configuration?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I have a project that compiles into a DLL. I am using a `.DEF` [file to manage the exported functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx).
For instance:

```
EXPORTS
    MyFoo1
    MyFoo2
    MyFoo3
    MyFoo4
```

Is it possible to have different `.DEF` files in `debug` and `release` configurations? I would like to have a larger set of functions in `debug` mode than in `release`.

For example, I would like to have in `release` mode only `MyFoo1`.

Currently I thought about using `__declspec` instead of `.DEF` file, and use some macro that will enable them only when the macro is on. The macro in turn, can be put into pre-processor definitions, which is dependent on build configuration.

Is it  possible to accomplish this goal without switching from `.DEF` files to `__declspec` mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a different DEF file for every build configuration :
Project properties -> Linker -> Input -> Module Definiton File

This sets the [/DEF option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34c30xs1.aspx)